# onPress is not working on elevated component, background is getting pressed

Tags: android, react-native, events

I elevated my header component and gave the paddingTop as the height of the header so that it looked just after the header.

But the problem is the buttons of the header are not getting pressed after than (before elevation they were getting pressed).

Later I come to know that the press is happening in the background padding and when I'm scrolling the content, the content which goes in the background of the header is getting pressed.

[image]

> Code:

```
header: {
        height: 75,
        elevation: 10,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
```

---

```
<View style={header}>
   ... Buttons ...
</View>

<ScrollView>
    <View style={{paddingTop: 75}} >
        ... List ...
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi siraz, have you find any soilution for this

Comment: No, not yet. BTW its Siraj not Siraz.

Comment: okay cool, let me know if you find the solution for it.

Comment: yeah sure. I will.